# How to share files with an iPad app in El Capitan itunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad, file-sharing

I have this iPad app called AVPlayer. I used to plug-in the iPad and copy files to the app using iTunes. However, this doesn't seem to work in the newest version of iTunes. There used to be a feature called ["file sharing"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5122648?start=0&tstart=0) that allowed to do that, but it seems to be gone now? I can still navigate to the "apps" panel, but AVPlayer doesn't show up there, in fact there is no app that would allow sending files to it, and no such option at all.

So the question is: how to send files to an iPad app via a usb cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should still be there on the Apps panel, though it's more confusingly-located than I seem to remember it used to be. You have to scroll right down past the Apps section where you can add/remove/arrange apps, and you'll eventually get to a File Sharing section with a list of apps that support file sharing.

[image]

If you found your way there but the list is empty, then something else is afoot... if nothing else, you should see the iWork apps there, if you have those installed.

Comment: Ah, damn the invisible scrollbar! I can't believe I couldn't figure it out for hours...